# Cannot get the object of a tabpanel

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a grid in the center region of a border layout. When a specific item is clicked in the grid, I need to change the center region to display a tab panel. I am having trouble getting the tabpanel object.

In the ctrlpanel file, on the grid listener, I am using componentQuery to get the tabpanel('ccmain') object. It returns undefined.

I was using componentQuery to get 'ccmain' in the centerpanel file(lays out center region) successfully, but when I moved this code to the ctrlpanel file(one of the  items in centerpanel) it fails. ComponentQuery no longer returns the tabpanel 'ccmain'. ComponentQuery does return the centerpanel or the viewport. I attemped to do centerpanel or viewport.down to find 'ccmain', but that also returns undefined. If you can tell me how to get the tabpanel or what I am doing wrong, I would appreciate it. Thanks for your time.

ctrlPanel.js

```
Ext.define('ServcSol.view.CtrlPanel',{
extend: 'Ext.Panel',

alias: 'widget.ctrlPanel',
xtype: 'ctrlPanel',
itemId: 'ctrlPanel',

requires:[
    'ServcSol.store.FacilityStore'
    ],

initComponent: function () {  

var me = this;

Ext.applyIf(me, {

items: [ 
{
  xtype: 'panel',
  height: 750,
  title: 'Control Panel',
  items: [
  {
   xtype: 'gridpanel',
   padding: '20 20 5 20',
   store: 'WorkHistoryStore',
   height: 590,
   width: '100%',
   border: true,
   columns: [
   {
     width: 110,
     dataIndex: 'wrkhistDate',
     text: 'Due Date'
   },
   {
     width: 100,
     dataIndex: 'wrkType',
     text: 'Work Type'
   }
 ], 
 listeners : {
   itemclick: function(dv, record, item, index, e) 
   {
     if(record.get('wrkType') == 'Test')
         {                   
           var tabPanel = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('ccmain')[0];
           console.log('tabPanel is: ', tabPanel);
           var tabIndex = tabPanel.items.findIndex('id', 'hazard');
           var center = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('centerpanel')[0];
           center.getLayout().setActiveTab(tabIndex);
     }
```

ccmain.js

```
Ext.define('ServcSol.view.ccMain', {
extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
itemId: 'ccmain',
alias: 'widget.ccmain',
xtype: 'ccmain',

initComponent: function () {

var me = this;

Ext.applyIf(me, {
items: [
      {
        xtype: 'facility'
      },
      {
        xtype: 'hazListing'
      },
      {
        xtype: 'hazard'
      }, 
      {
        xtype: 'testFormRP'
      },
      {
        xtype: 'testFormDC'
      } 
       ]
    });      
  this.callParent(arguments);
  }
 });
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. You're trying to set the active component as a string.

Comment: Sorry, typing error. The code is not getting to that point because componentQuery is not returning 'ccmain'. Edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons can be that `ccmain` is not instantiated as only instantiated components can be found by `ComponentQuery.query`. Then, even if `ccmain` would be found you cannot set its active item that way. Easiest is to assign tabs `itemIds` and then call [setActiveTab](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel-method-setActiveTab):

```
tabPanel.setActiveTab(itemIdOfTheTab)
```